# xgboost.core.XGBoostError:/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/xgboost-split_1631904775127/work/src/common/json.cc:458

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, xgboost

I am using XGboost library for prediction. When I want to load a pickle file, I encounter the following error:

```
File "/Users/admin/space/ML/model_building/predictor.py", line 74, in load_regressor
    self._regressor = pickle.load(f)
  File "/Users/admin/.conda/envs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 1496, in __setstate__
    _check_call(
  File "/Users/admin/.conda/envs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 203, in _check_call
    raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: [16:23:50] /Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/xgboost-split_1631904775127/work/src/common/json.cc:458: Expecting: """, got: "76 ", around character position: 1
    {L\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
    ^~~~~~~~~
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) 1   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000014c7dce74 dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal() + 116
  [bt] (1) 2   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000014c80e5ce xgboost::JsonReader::Error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) const + 1070
  [bt] (2) 3   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000014c80f09b xgboost::JsonReader::Expect(char, char) + 299
  [bt] (3) 4   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000014c80f93b xgboost::JsonReader::ParseObject() + 491
  [bt] (4) 5   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000014c80e068 xgboost::JsonReader::Parse() + 456
  [bt] (5) 6   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000014c813fce xgboost::Json::Load(xgboost::StringView) + 62
  [bt] (6) 7   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000014c893a2f xgboost::LearnerIO::Load(dmlc::Stream*) + 607
  [bt] (7) 8   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000014c7e822f XGBoosterUnserializeFromBuffer + 159
  [bt] (8) 9   libffi.8.dylib                      0x000000010e368d92 ffi_call_unix64 + 82
```

The pickle file is already tested on the other machines and it works well, but in my machine, with the same version of XGboost (1.6.1), I get this error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to load there - an `xgboost.Booster` object, or something else?

According to the error message, you've passed an `xgboost.Booster` bytestream to the standard Python `pickle.load` function. This doesn't make sense.

Pay attention, the `pickle.load` function is complaining that the datastream starts with `{L`, which indicates XGBoost Universal Binary JSON (UBJSON) data format. You could load this datastream like `xgboost.Booster(model_file = 'mymodel.ubj')`